# Django model function implementation to auto initialize a particular field's value

Tags: python, sql, django

I need to write a `Django` model function to calculate the value of an existing field.

my `models.py`:

```
class questionNumeric(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    marks = models.IntegerField()
    correctAns = models.FloatField()

class questionTureFalse(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    marks = models.IntegerField()
    correctAns = models.BooleanField()

class questionSet(models.Model):
    examName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    questionNumeric = models.ManyToManyField(questionNumeric)
    questionTureFalse = models.ManyToManyField(questionTureFalse)
    totalMarks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

As you can see here, each `questionNumeric` or `questionTureFalse` object has specific `marks`. Now I want to set my `questionSet` object's `totalMarks` field with- the summation of marks carried by all `questionNumeric` or `questionTureFalse` under this `questionSet` object.

How can I write a Django Model function under `questionSet` to auto initialize `totalMarks`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a function in `questionSet` and return count of relations. For example sth like:

```py
class QuestionSet(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_question_numeric_count(self):
        return self.questionNumeric.count()
```